# Ionic Cordova Themeable Browser - prevent youtube video to play in background

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I’m using themeable browser to view web pages, and some of them have youtube videos in iframe. I’m having trouble with the video still running in the background (switch app or lock screen). Is there any configuration of the Themeable Browser or Ionic Cordova to prevent this behavior?

Web pages are under my control, if the solution is better on the page itself.

My Environment:

Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI): 4.3.1
Ionic Framework: Ionic-angular 3.9.2
@ ionic / app-scripts: 3.0.0

Cordova:

Cordova (Cordova CLI): 8.0.0
Cordova Platforms: android 7.0.0
Cordova Plugins: no whitelisted plugins (11 total plugins)

System:

Android SDK Tools: 26.1.1 (/ home / phpinheiro / Android / Sdk)
NodeJS: v10.1.0 (/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/node/10.1.0/bin/node)
npm: 5.6.0
OS: Linux 4.18

Plugin: cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser 0.2.17 “ThemeableBrowser”

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser](https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser) is a fork of the official [cordova-plugin-inappbrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser), it does not contain the more recent fixes from the latter, including the ability to pause playing videos when entering the background.

This issue was raised against `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` as [CB-11013](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11013) and subsequently added as a feature via the `shouldPauseOnSuspend=yes` option.

However, this change has not been patched over to `cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser`.

So your options are to switch over to using `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`, find a fork of `cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser` that has been patched, or fork `cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser` and patch it yourself.

Comment: Hmmm, guess I'll have to switch to inAppBrowser then. Even because the Themeable Browser is out of maintenance.

Thank you for pointing out an official solution.